# What's the distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

$$X_1,X_2,...,X_n \text{ i.i.d with density function}$$
$$f(x)=e^{-(x-\theta)}\;,x\ge\theta$$

What is the distribution of $\bar X$?

I gained m.g.f  of $\bar X$. (by calculating $E[e^{1/n (X_1+\cdots+X_n)}])$

Result is ${(\frac n {n-t}})^{n}e^{ {t\theta} }$.

But I don't know distribution that has this m.g.f(moment generating function).

What is the distribution?

My process is wrong ?

Please answer...

Comment: It's a shifted Gamma distribution.

Comment: shifted Gamma distribution? 
Do you know pdf of shifted Gamma distribution ?